# Is incremental adds are possible in neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a quick question. I have database of one million nodes and 4 million relationships. This all data in neo4j i have created with import csv command. Now after testing the graph database and analyzing the queries according to my need. Now i want to make a php program where the data will be automatically loaded and i will get the results in the end (according to my query). Now here is the question, as my data will update after 15 min. Is neo4j has a ability of incremental adds. Like to show which new relationships or nodes added in this specific time.i was thinking to use the time command to see which data was created in that time. Correct me if i am wrong. i only want to see the new addition. because i dont want neo4j to waste time on the calculation of already existing nodes/relationships.is there any other way to do that. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an interesting use case and it is valuable IMO. I don't see any possibility out of the box right now except a combination of the GraphAware Timetree with the GraphAware ChangeFeed module. But I opened an issue on our plugin to see if we can implement this feature : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-changefeed/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to store a string of the date/time that the nodes are added.  Then you could query for everything since the last date/time.  I'm not 100% sure on the index performance of that, though.

However, if all you care about is showing the the most recently imported, you could have a boolean value with an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(recently_added)
```

Then when you import your data you can unset all of the current ones and set the new ones like this:

```
MATCH (n:Label {recently_added: true})
REMOVE n.recently_added
```

Second query:

```
MATCH (n:Label {id: {id_list}})
SET n.recently_added = true
```

That is assuming that you have some sort of unique identifier on the nodes which you can use to set the ones which you just added.

Comment: thanks brian, but dont you think thats more like sliding window.

Comment: I think I thought that's what you meant.  Could you give an example?